# Disconnected from the Metro server. Reload to reconnect

Tags: react-native, expo

Using RN with Expo, I've started getting the `Disconnected from the Metro server. Reload to reconnect` error to appear pretty much every time after hitting Save.

I found this - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12786 and https://github.com/facebook/metro/commit/079dcaed990abb6754c03113362e4f537cd32a24 - but I'm not sure where to change the flag, or how to disable xip stuff (or if that's even the root cause).

If anyone has seen this, can you please shed some light?

Expo v36.
RN - sdk-36.0.1
Mac 10.13.6

Thanks.